# Automapper (C#): Nested mappings not working

Tags: c#, automapper, inner-classes

I have a simple mapping and it is working but it's not filling in Output.Details.

I am a bit confused, I think it maybe because I am using the source as "Task" for each one.

```
  Mapper.CreateMap<Task, Output>();


  Mapper.CreateMap<Task, Output.Details>().ForMember(
       dest => dest.Item, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

As far as i know i have to create 2 maps, 1 for the object and 1 for object contained within.

Problem is the source for the OUTPUT and OUTPUT.DETAILS can be found in TASK

I tried delving into Details within the first map and specifying Mapfrom but it gives the following error which is why i must create 2 maps

```
         must resolve to top-level member. Parameter name: lambdaExpression error

  IList<Task> tempItems= GetItems();

        IList<Output> items =
            Mapper.Map<IList<Task>, IList<Output>>(tempItems);
```

The map works but my property "Item" availble in Output.Details is NULL

What am I doing wrong? Here is my Destination object.

It fills in Name no problem, but nothing inside DETAILS... they are left NULL.

Task is not my class, but I checked it and all values are there to be copied hence Tag has a value and is a STRING.

```
public class Output   
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Details Summary { get; private set; }
 
    public class Details
    {
        public string Item{ get; set; }
    }

    public Output()
    {
        Summary = new Details();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the Task class.

[image]

**EDIT**

They is a sample vs 2010 project here and it shows exactly the problem.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20103903/AutomapperNotWorking.zip

and here is an image showing the issue, as you can see Summary Item is "NULL" but it should contain the NAME from Task.

[image]

Comment: What does Task look like?  Can you should the class definition for Task?  And what is "Properties" in your Output constructor?  It doesn't appear in the class anywhere.

Comment: Hi Patrick, thanks alot for the reply. Properties was a typo :-) sorry its Sumary actually.. it creates the instance.. i updated the question and also  i have included an image of the Task.. task is not my class

Comment: What do you want Output.Summary to contain?  You don't have an Ignore() set up for it, but Task doesn't have a Summary property?  Right now, it's hard to help since you don't have a valid mapping configuration to start with.  Is there any way you could create a temporary Task class that reproduces the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Hi Patrick, Well its working as far Output.Name gets filled from Task.Name this is because Name and Name exist in each class Task and Output so i don't need a MapFrom... as they match. Output.Details.Name isn't filled. its NULL...  I am trying to fill it (as a test) from Task.Name ... hence they don't match up so i am doing a MapFrom Task.Name >>>>> Output.Details.Name.  Does this help?   My Output class has Output.Name, and Output.Details BUT inside Output.Details the Name is = null... There is NO MAPPING taking place.

Comment: I even confirmed this by changing the MapFrom to ResolveUsing and setup a resolver and placed a breakpoint in it... It never enters...

Comment: Lets take an example like this, if i had Task.Name and Task.Details and Task.Details.Name  and then Output.Name and Output.Details and Output.Details.Name - for sure its going to work because everything matches up... My problem is i have a Flat file (task) which i need to populate my Output which has a nested type.. but i need to populate from Task. Flat file > nested type... I know i am doing something stupid... but it doesn't give me an error when i do an Assert the map config.

Comment: To confirm OutPut.Details (which is an instance of Summary) needs to be instantiated and its is :-)  its the property inside Details i need to populate from Task.Name as well.

Comment: Sorry Martin, but I'm just not understanding what your issue is.  It's difficult to figure out without a reproducible test case -- can you provide one?  I'm confused because you're talking about Summary as a type (when it's a property name) and Details as a property name (when it's a Type).

Comment: hi patrick.. thanks for sticking with me on this, yes damb typo! i meant to say Details in place of summary. Ok Patrick.. i am going to create a visual studio 2010 project with an example and i will upload it later.  Thanks again... i have to pop out now but i will be back.. i will have it uploaded in about 4 hours.....  Thanks once again...

Comment: Actually scratch that.. i am doing it now... give me 30 mins or so i will send you the link to have a look. It will be a vs 2010 console project.. i presume you have it.

Comment: Hi Patrick.. ok i have uploaded a real project.. I create my own Task because as i explained its not my Class.. but with my "MOCK" class it shows the error as well..  i.e ITEM = null but ITEM = NAME from TASK

Comment: the link is contained in my original message above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, always use `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();` to make sure your mapping configuration is valid.  I added it to your code and it immediately highlighted the problem: You didn't tell Automapper what to do with the Summary property.  Since Task doesn't contain a property called Summary, Automapper needs to know what to do with it.

So the problem isn't really how to map a nested class, you just need to tell Automapper what to do with Summary.  Here's the Automapper configuration that works for your example:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Task, Output>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Summary, o => o.MapFrom(t => new Output.Details {Item = t.Name}));
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

That's all you need.

Comment: Wow patrick! yes i always include the assert but building the sample app i forgot.. ooops!  This works great but i am a little confused. On the docs http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nested%20Mappings&referringTitle=Home  it states i need to create 2 maps.. 1 for Task, Output and the other for Output.Details.  What you sent me works great! But you it is creating the class on the fly.

Comment: According to the example here http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Nested%20Mappings&referringTitle=Home  (if its not out of date! must be it doesn't work fro me :-) ) it states i create 2 maps.. 1 for outer and 1 for inner... this is exactly what i am doing isn't it ..i have an outer and an  inner?? so setting the 2 maps and doing map should work?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on this, any help you offer to make me understand why it doesn't work as per the codeplex example would be really helpful

Comment: In the codeplex example, the property names of the inner classes on source and dest are the same.  In fact, the overall class structure of both is the same.  With the same property names, Automapper will check to see if it knows how to convert from the source type to the dest type (which, in the example, it does).  You don't have that same setup.  You've got a flat class (Task) you want mapped to both a class as well as a member of that class (sort of a 1-to-many that Automapper doesn't really support).

Comment: wow thanks Patrick for sticking with me on this,!  i understand it now a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

for the new version, it can be performed as follow:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<UdtDevQuestion, QuestionViewModel>();
});
config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```